# Get Office Addin Publish Version

Tags: c#, version, add-in, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook Addin and I need to get the Publish Version.
I dont mean the Assembly Version, File Version or Office Version. (Which is all I found).

Some C# Code would be pretty nice!

[image]

The black XML is from the Project File.

Answer (score 6):

Very late but may help someone else :)

Works with my deployed Vsto Outlook AddIn (Will not work in debug mode).

use **System.Deployment.Application** namespace from **System.Deployment** assembly

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    ApplicationDeployment applicationDeployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;

    Version version = applicationDeployment.CurrentVersion;

    return  String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build, version.Revision);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks, works great! I used the ToString() function of the Version object which gives the same result as your String.Format.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this is a late reply but hopefully this should help you if you havent already found your solution or it should help somebody else working on a similar issue.

Give this a go. You can extract the current version and then get each part of it and combine them as a string. You will need to add the System.Deployment reference to your project.

```
using System.Deployment.Application;

    public Version Version 
    {
        get
        {
            return ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
        }
    }


    string versionNumber = Version.Major.ToString() + "." + Version.Minor.ToString() + "." + Version.Build.ToString() + "." + Version.Revision.ToString();
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, Thanks a lot. Im still looking for a solution. I found this already on the web, but I just get the Error that System.Deployment.Application doesnt exist. I only have System.Deployment.Internal. :(
Or do I just have to reference System.Deployment Assembly? I expected this should work without an additional Assembly. I will try it.

Comment: I get now an InvalidDeploymentException: "Application identity is not set."

Comment: I found that this only works when the Addin is deployed via ClickOnce. So this doesnt work with debugging.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was just adding this to my outlook addin and I got the same problem as you. You need to add the System.Deployment reference to your project.