# VSTO get the publication version of my add in

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsto

I've made a VSTO Excel Addin. I need to put in a label the version of my addin.
I can get the assembly version,

```
Dim ver As String = MessageBox.Show(Globals.ThisAddIn.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString())
```

With the Global class I can't retrive too the version of the publication...

Dim ver2 As String = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Version

but I need to see the publication version. There is any way?

[image]

Comment: What is it 'publication version'? Is it your setting?

Comment: No, it isn't my setting....is the version that automatically increments with each publication

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941288/how-can-i-get-the-executing-assembly-version

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282560/get-office-addin-publish-version).  Looks like it doesn't work in debug mode.

Comment: You're right, I expected to see a result in debug. Now it works well